# Laravel to automatically handle a cast in a query

Tags: php, laravel

I have been playing with Laravel casting for a little while now, it is extremely useful and saves a lot of hassle. However one issue I have found is that when you want to query the database with your cast you must specify the `->withCasts('fieldname' => YourCast::class)` option.

An example cast being used is to convert a hexadecimal string to an integer, meaning that if you want to query a model field

`Model::where('hex' => 'FF')`

Would not work, so you would need to include the cast

`Model::where('hex' => 'FF')->withCasts(['hex' => HexType::class])`

However if you were to want to use an integer there is no need for the `->withCasts()` option because that is the native database type

`Model::where('hex', 255)`

Just a note, the `set()` function has been written up to handle both strings and integers, however I and my colleagues or new developers are inevitably forgetful. If there are a lot of casts to make, and with MySQL refusing to rule out that 'FF' is an integer, writing and reviewing the queries can be time consuming at best.

What I want to know then is whether Laravel has a function or a flag to automatically add this to any query builder, so as not to have to go through the hassle of having to write this out every time. Essentially if this is not the case it would probably be better to do away with casts because it will probably introduce too many bugs. I am aware that this is not possible to query e.g. encrypted data, however when the typecasting is immutable is there is a way to automatically tell it to do cast into the correct data type?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you do include `->when(condition, callback)` in your query, for example:

```
$value = 'FF';

Model::where('hex', $value)->when(!is_numeric($value), function($query){
   $query->withCasts(['hex' => HexType::class])
});
```

with this the "cast" is applied as long as the value is not a number, you could also create a local scope to simplify the query. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#local-scopes

Even so, I would like to see the code of the "HexType" class to better understand the problem, maybe i'm wrong

Comment: The cast type is not vital to the question. I am looking for a way for `->where()` to be able to support both `'FF'` and `255` without having to write extra code since the `->set()` function inside of the cast should be converting it automatically (in this instance to an integer).